# How to calculate how many intervals at given daterange? simpler version

Tags: postgresql

I can write:

```
select count(*) from generate_series( 
    '2019-03-01'::date, '2019-05-01'::date, 
    interval '3 day 1 hour' 
) 
-- exclude upper boundary
where generate_series <> date '2019-05-01'::date;
```

Is there a way to do it simpler? like:

```
daterange( '2019-03-01', '2019-05-01' ) / interval '3 day 1 hour'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
EXTRACT(epoch FROM some_interval)
```

to get an interval's duration in seconds.

You could use that as follows:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(epoch FROM '2019-05-01'::timestamptz - '2019-03-01'::timestamptz)
       / EXTRACT(epoch FROM interval '3 day 1 hour');
```

Note that this will only give correct answers for intervals that are measured in days or lesser units; for months and more you have to go with your original solution.

Comment: This does not fit. Because depending on interval: `1day` or `1hour`, I get different results on `DST` days

Comment: I don't understand. I have added sample code to my answer. Could you explain what is wrong about the result?

Comment: Sorry, I added example directly into your answer. Feel free to delete it if you are not agree with it.

Comment: I will delete it from the answer, not because it is not helpful, but because it is not part of an answer. If you need to handle months correctly, you have to go with your original idea. You cannot do that except by successively adding month after month to the start date. But my solution should work well for everything that is measured in days or less (as it was in your question).

Comment: Ok. actually my interval can be any: `month`, `year` etc. Probably your answer do right calculations but it is not simple

Comment: My answer is simple in that it is cheap.